# JavaScript doesn't load when page refresh

Tags: javascript, java

I'm having a issue with my page refresh with a External Exception in use.

```
    if(sendTOList.isEmpty()) {
         ShowableDoc docMsgError = new ShowableDoc();
         docMsgError.addField("msg", "sample_text");
         return new SessionHtml( getErrorFile(), docMsgErro, session );
     }
```

I have this Java code sample here, when sendTOList is empty, refresh the page and then return a external exception above it. But when page refresh, JS doesn't load at all. Can someone help me?

Comment: It's very difficult to say what is the issue just by looking at the code. Is there someway you can create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?